# Laravel eloquent pivot table model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a problem in laravel eloquent.

I have 3 tables: `members`, `subscriptions` and a pivot table for a many-to-many relationship between members and subscriptions:  `member_subscription`.

I have another table that is tied on `member_subscription`, with check-ins for member subscription.

What I need is to define the relationship between `member_subscription` and `check-ins`. I read something about a custom model for the pivot table, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please share table structure.

Comment: Hi @Ionut, welcome to SO. Please have a look on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add missing information to your question. Currently there is a bit of  information missing on what you already tried. Please be so kind and provide all the information you can give so others are able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model for the `member_subscription`. Then, when you query the relationship between `members` and `subscriptions`, you can use the `using` function.

In the Member model:

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription')->using('App\MemberSubscription');
}
```

In the Subscription model:

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member')->using('App\MemberSubscription');
}
```

Now, in your `MemberSubscription` model, define the relationship to checkins:

```
public function checkins()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Checkins');
}
```

Now you can do stuff like:

```
$member->subscriptions()->first()->pivot; // Returns a MemberSubscription model
$member->subscriptions()->first()->pivot->checkins;
```